# How to trigger keyup() while using autocomplete()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change the first letter of a word to uppercase. So, I have written some code on `keyup()` function.

Whenever I type inside the text filed, Word's first letter is getting changed to uppercase.

I also use `autocomplete()` function. The problem is, Whenever I choose a word from autocomplete drop down it's first letter is not getting changed to uppercase and also the last text box is getting auto focused.

FYI: I am triggering the `keyup()` function after the autocomplete selection.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ke04mgs/5/

Comment: Why do you need `keyup()` event? Already `autocomplete()` uses `keypress()` and it works fine right?

Comment: you said " Whenever I choose a word from autocomplete drop down it's first letter is not getting changed to uppercase and also the last text box is getting auto focused." But i can see in your fiddle your first letter is getting changed to uppercase when you type in the autocomplete textbox...and the last text is shown from the second character .So what is your question actually . This post and your fiddle are different.

Comment: No, same only. whenever I type inside the textbox it's working fine. But while typing itself some suggestions will be shown in the drop down. After selecting any one of the suggestions from the drop down letter is not changed to uppercase. Did I explain clearly?

Comment: so you want the letters gets changed to uppercase when you type in or select any suggestions ?

Comment: and for the text-box that is showing up after second character is typed in ...when you want that to show ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use change event on your textbox

```
$(document).on('change', 'inputBox', function() {
  // Does some stuff and logs the event to the console
});
```

This will solve the autocomplete problem

Answer (score 0):

Your current way of doing things would work perfectly if the select method you provide to the autocomplete library was called after value of the box was updated.
But it is not, it's called before and so the value that it capitalises is the old value and is immediately replaced by autocomplete anyway.

As @Alok has pointed out, you can use the 'change' event to wait a little longer.

To avoid writing out your event handler out twice, remember `.on()` can take multiple events, so I'd just call it on keyup and change like so

```
$('#element').on('keyup change', function() {
    ...
});
```

But I think in modern browsers 'change' should be enough.